# querySelectorAll checked values

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter, selectors-api

I have a list/group of checkboxes, that made by php; put in name="item[]" html property, and then follow with this:

```
 var list = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='item[']")
```

So far, works well. I need to count only the checked ones, not all like:

```
 list.length
```

How can I access the values for eachone to check "checked" property or value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rather than looking through your list, you can go back and ask `querySelectorAll` to return just the [checked items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked):

```
var checkedList = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='item[']:checked")
```

Comment: typo: extra [ in "input[name^='item[']:checked"

Comment: @MarioTheHedgehog There isn’t - the one in the single quotes (`item[`) is part of the name we’re matching against, the brackets outside of that surround the entire attribute of the `input` element we’re looking for.